# Apply CommandBars functionality in Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, calendar, outlook

I created macros to automate the creation of new calendar appointments and to edit existing calendar appointments in Outlook 2010.

Since upgrading to Outlook 2013 the macro no longer works. I don't get any error message.

```
Sub NewCustomAppt()
'objects
Dim objExpl As Outlook.Explorer
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objCB As Office.CommandBarButton
'appointment
Dim objAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim objApptCustom As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment

Dim objNS

Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

On Error Resume Next

Set objExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer

If Not objExpl Is Nothing Then
    Set objFolder = objExpl.CurrentFolder
    If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olAppointmentItem Then
        Set objCB = objExpl.CommandBars.FindControl(, 1106)
        If Not objCB Is Nothing Then
            objCB.Execute
            Set objAppt = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
            Set objApptCustom =   
            objFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Appointment.your_custom_class")

            Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

            With objApptCustom
                .Start = objAppt.Start
                .End = objAppt.End            

                objAppt.Location = "Careers Service, Level 6 Livingstone Tower"
                objAppt.ReminderSet = True
                objAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 4320

                objAppt.Body = "If you wish to cancel or re-schedule this    
                    appointment please let us know as soon as possible, by telephone:          
                     0141 548 4320 or email: yourcareer@strath.ac.uk." & vbNewLine & _
                    "" & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please make sure you are prompt for your appointment, if you are 
                     more than 10 minutes late you will not be seen by the adviser." 
                     & vbNewLine & _
                     & vbNewLine & _
                     & vbNewLine & _
                     "Your Careers Adviser for this appointment is:" & vbNewLine & _
                     "" & vbNewLine & _
                     "" & vbNewLine & _
                     In order to prepare for your appointment with your Careers Adviser 
                     please read through the information attached below" 
                     & vbNewLine & _
                     "" & vbNewLine & _
                  "" & vbNewLine & _
                  "" & vbNewLine & _
                  "" & vbNewLine & _
                  "" & vbNewLine & _
                    "This appointment was created on the " & Date & " at" & " " & Time 
                     & vbNewLine & _
                     objAppt.Attachments.Add "I:\Admin\Careers\INTERVIEW.DOC
                     'Add the attachment to the e-mail message.

                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the On Error Resume Next and run it.

Comment: Hi. Tried that but still not working?

Comment: And still no error message?

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft:

Command bars are not used in Outlook 2013. CommandBar functions will fail silently.

Use the IRibbonExtensibility interface in an Outlook 2013 add-in instead of command bars. You can’t customize Inspector ribbons by using VBScript code behind forms.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178954%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

.FindControl(, 1106) works in 2010 so if there is a silent fail in 2013 switch to ExecuteMso

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862419.aspx

```
Private Sub NewCustomAppt_ExecuteMso()

    'objects
    Dim objExpl As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder

    'appointment
    Dim objAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.attachment

    Dim objNS
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer

    If Not objExpl Is Nothing Then

        Set objFolder = objExpl.CurrentFolder

        If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olAppointmentItem Then

            objExpl.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("NewAppointment") ' <----
            Set objAppt = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

            objAppt.location = "Careers Service, Level 6 Livingstone Tower"
            objAppt.ReminderSet = True
            objAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 4320

            objAppt.body = "If you wish to cancel or re-schedule this "

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

The IdMso can be seen if you hover over the command when modifying ribbons or the QAT.